Pytorch OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
I'm using PyTorch library in Python. I keep getting this error down below. The error happens on the line Import torch

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error
loading
"C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll"
or one of its dependencies.

I installed all required dependencies and used Microsoft Visual tools to check the dependencies. I got the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. I tried everything I could find but nothing worked. How do I fix this?

Following this solution worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ca34C8ZUI0A
